# Do you know analog to panTo and setView in mapbox api 2.4.0?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

**Hello.**

I'm moving from Leaflet.js to Mapbox.
When I read the docs for the `setView` and `panTo` in Mapbox, I saw that this old doc for 2.2.0 (for Javascript).

Is there some analog to these methods in Mapbox, or is it better to use MapboxGL?

Comment: Do you want the methods [`setView` (link to Docs)](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-setview) and [`panTo` (link to Docs)](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-panto) in Leaflet.js?  Or are you moving from Leaflet.js to Mapbox?

Comment: Moving from leaflet to mapbox.

Comment: I've edited your question to clarify this.  Please feel free to edit the question more to reflect your intentions.